# Why i'm getting ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to post data to some 3rd party client URL. When I tried to POST from Postman it's working fine. However, when I tried to call it form jQuery AJAX it's showing this error:

> net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Is this error from my side or from 3rd party client?

Here is my jQuery code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https://11.11.11.11.123/abc/def/blabla',
  headers: {
    'X-Foo': 'bar'
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(feederData),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data === true) {
      alert();
    }
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    alert(a);
  }
});
```

FYI I'm calling `HTTPS` service.

Comment: The issue is because the SSL certificate on your `https://11.11.11.11.123` domain is not valid for the IP address you're using.

Comment: you have to send data as object and not as string - the api has to handle the object as post array with several arguments

Comment: @mtizziani it's better practice, but you don't *have* to

Comment: @mtizziani, I think that's not a problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. So, i'm going to report that bug to them. Can i proceed?

Comment: You can do whatever you feel is required, although the address you're using is very odd, for a start it's not a valid IP. I originally read it as an IP address with a port mapping, but that's not the case. If you want to get rid of this error I'd suggest changing the URL to use the domain name that matches the SSL cert.

Comment: looks like a ssl certification problem -> https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7391219?hl=en , you have to enable the access to self made certificates first by open the api domain and accept the cert

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, in my question i placed dummy IP. But, in reality that's different.

Comment: Ah ok, well that explains it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use domain that created ssl certificate on, not ip. the certificates are located on xxxyy.com domain folder, use exactly that domain name.